# How to create a shadow pixi.js?

Tags: pixi.js

Why are there no shadow? What you need to do to make the filter work? If possible then show me in code how to create a shadow.

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(500, 200, {
  transparent: true
});

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();

function update(){
  renderer.render(stage);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0x848484);
graphics.drawPolygon([0,0,100,0,100,100,0,100,0,0]);
graphics.endFill();

var dropShadowFilter = new PIXI.filters.DropShadowFilter();
dropShadowFilter.alpha = 1;
dropShadowFilter.blur = 2;
dropShadowFilter.distance = 20;

graphics.filters = [dropShadowFilter];

stage.addChild(graphics);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.7/pixi.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the renderer transparent. I guess, if the renderer is transparent, then it's texture has alpha = 0 and the shadow is drawn on that. Also, only works for webGL.

```js
var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(500, 200);
renderer.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();

function update(){
  renderer.render(stage);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0x8484cc);
graphics.drawPolygon([20,20,120,20,120,120,20,120,20,20]);
graphics.endFill();

var dropShadowFilter = new PIXI.filters.DropShadowFilter();
dropShadowFilter.color = 0x000020;
dropShadowFilter.alpha = 0.2;
dropShadowFilter.blur = 6;
dropShadowFilter.distance = 20;

graphics.filters = [dropShadowFilter];

stage.addChild(graphics);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.7/pixi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does not work with pixi.js v4: *Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.filters.DropShadowFilter is not a constructor(…)*

Comment: @AlexanderFarber If you refer to this: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2075 . It says it has been moved to "pixi-filters", a separate library. Though I don't see it listed on the page.

Comment: For anyone aving the same issue the library has been moved here https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-filters